# Load in images to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am getting an error loading in images from folders. I have loaded in the following:

```
base_path = '/Users/rayday/Desktop/COMP309_2020_Project/'
train_dir = '/Users/rayday/Desktop/COMP309_2020_Project/Train_data/'
test_dir ='/Users/rayday/Desktop/COMP309_2020_Project/ProjectTemplate_python3.7/data/test/'
```

When I run the below chunk of code

```
print('Training Data')
for direc in os.listdir(train_dir):
    print(direc, ':',len(os.listdir(train_dir+direc)))
```

I get an error saying 'Not a directory'.

Comment: Did you even read the error? And understand what your code is doing? There are 0 images involved here. 'Not a directory' means that the element 'direc' is not a directory. Which is not surprising as os.listdir(train_dir) will list every element in this folder, including files. Thus, when applying os.listdir(train_dir + direc), you try to list the content of a file as if it was a directory.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to do this is with the glob module, for example:

```
import glob

image_paths = glob.glob('images/*.jpg')

for image_path in image_paths:
    # Load image
    original_image = Image.open(image_path)
```